# How to replace numbers in text with numbers in the array with AHK?

Tags: arrays, regex, autohotkey

Clipboard content = 10,19,2023,19,6,2,9   (this is a variable array)

Sentence with numbers to modify:

From 4  to 6 July 2023, we attended 10 meetings, including 5 discussions, 25 exhibits and 3 briefings.

Modified Sentence:

From 9  to 9 July 9, we attended 9 meetings, including 9 discussions, 9 exhibits and 9 briefings.

The problem:  only the last number in the array is applied correctly.  Any idea how to fix my code? Thanks

```
^!2::
    ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard :=
    Send, ^x
    ClipWait, 2
    CutText := Clipboard
    Clipboard := ClipSaved
    regex := "\b\d+\b"
    replacedText := CutText
    Loop % copiedNumbers.Length()
    {
    replacedText := RegExReplace(replacedText, regex, copiedNumbers[A_Index])
    }
    Clipboard := replacedText
    Send, ^v
return
```

Comment: @Wiktor Thank you for the suggestion. That did not solve the problem. It only made the clipboard content to be pasted repeatedly according to the number of items in the array. In this case 7 times.

Comment: OK, so you want to replace *any* number in the text with `9`, right? Then why use the loop in the first place? Just use `replacedText := RegExReplace(replacedText, regex, copiedNumbers[A_Index])` once, shouldn't it work already?

Comment: @Wiktor No. Numbers in the array (10,19,2023,19,6,2,9) should replace numbers in the sentence to modify. 10 should replace 4; 19 should replace 6 and so on2 ... The problem is the last number in the array is used to replace everything.

Comment: I see now. I doubt this is possible in AHK. In other languages, there is a way to pass the match to an anonymous function used as a replacement argument, and here, I do not think it supports such function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this in ahk v2:

```
variable := "10,19,2023,19,6,2,9"
text := "From 4 to 6 July 2023, we attended 10 meetings, including 5 discussions, 25 exhibits and 3 briefings."

replacedText := RegExReplace(text, "(.*?)\d+", "$1*")

for i, v in StrSplit(variable, ",") {
    replacedText := RegExReplace(replacedText, "(.*?)\*(.*)", "$1" . v . "$2")
}

MsgBox(replacedText)
```

You replace all occurrences of numbers in the original string with "*" and then for each number in your "variable array" you replace a single star until there are no numbers left. This doesn't account for a mismatch in the amount of numbers in the string and variable array however.